# How to create deprecation warnings when using old namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, deprecation-warning

I have a python package with a large number of subpackages and I've recently rewritten a good chunk of it and renamed and reorganized the packages and objects.

For example, in the past, I would import something like

```
from package import MyClass
```

but now, it should be

```
from package.subpackage import MyClass
```

For backwards compatibility, I've created symbols in the old locations that import and use the modules and objects from the new namespaces.

In `/package/__init__.py`

```
from .subpackage import MyClass
```

Is there a way to raise a deprecation warning when someone tries to import or access one of the old namespace locations?  With a class I could use `__getattr__`.  Is there a similar mechanism for catching attribute access on modules and packages?